# how a jsp function execute when javascript's function call?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jsp-tags

```
<script language="javascript"> 
var counter=0; 
var i=1;
function saveclick() 
{ 
<%j++;%>

    if(counter==3)
    { 
alert(counter);

}


else {

document.getElementById("error").innerHTML ="<%=qarr[j]%>"

  }
}

</script>
```

here i am using a qarr an array of String and its return String of corresponding index of array.
But when i click on button this javascripts' saveclick function execute but innerhtml shows only one String all times.
I want that when i click on button then js function execute and every  time new String appear in innerHtml.
please do needful in this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Jsp` plays on server side and   `javascript` plays on client side.

`Java` needs compiled code and `Javascript` is just a scripting language interpreted by the browser.

You need to either make a request to `server`(`HTML` forms/`AJAX`) for new content or Maintain `Json object` in client side itself while page loading and use it later.

But **You cannot mix them**.

Comment: thanks brother. I am using ajax in my project

Answer (score 0):

The JSP page is returned from the server as HTML page containing Javascript. The data from the server is returned only once. You can return a single string from the server with a separator, and then parse it in Client side (Javascript). You can also send data back and forth between the server and client, using some Ajax for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute jsp from your javascript function by implementing [ajax method](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_example.asp).